# DSE Graph Database "Is" relation representation in groovy

Tags: groovy, graph-databases, datastax-enterprise-graph

[image]

I am having difficulty, in understanding this Graph. 
I understand that

> Org and Persons are vertices and 'has vendor','Has Customer' and 'Has Employee' are the Edges, but i am not able to understand what is meant by ***"isMerchant"*** here in the picture attached

the name is quite intuitive, the Org is of Type Merchant,

but how can i represent the same in Groovy ?

something thing like this for edge

```
 schema.edgeLabel('Has Vendor').connection('Org',
 'Person').ifNotExists().create()
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the link for this diagram?  Based on the proximity of Merchant to Org and the colors used to denote some "meaning", it appears as if Merchant may be a Property of Org.  If that's the case, then simply creating a property for Merchant and adding it to the Org vertex will provide the desired results.

If Merchant is a separate Vertex, then creating an "Is Merchant" edge like what you've described will provide the desired results.

Gremlin's DDL is used to create schema for DSE Graph - http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/createSchemaStudio.html